# Why does JavaScript returns different outputs for the mathematically similar expression?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have 3 variables

```
var a = 0.1 
var b = 0.2 
var c = 0.3
```

Why does `(a + b) + c` gives `0.6000000000000001` and `a + (b + c)` gives `0.6`?